# Where is the Leave a Comment link set

Tags: comments

I have a self hosted WordPress blog and use the Isabella Theme from BluChic. The initial installation of this was set up via an auto installer that the host provider offered.

I moved the blog from one domain to another and in the process took the initial install and moved all the files. I had to do some changes in the db export to update the url to get everything working.

Everything works fine apart from the submit link for the Leave a Comment button. Does anyone know where this link is stored? I have all the files downloaded locally and have access to the database but so far I have no luck finding where this link is set.

The problem is the link is there but it points to the old domain address, even though all of the other links updated. This is the only link giving me hassle. It appears when you press post on the comment edit box that is popped up after clicking Leave a Reply

Any help on its location would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you see it when you use the default theme?

Comment: It does not work on any theme. To be clear the link is there, it is pointing to the old domain name, not the new one. This is the only link affected.

Answer (score 0):

Some plugins and I guess themes save the initial URLs and paths in their configuration files. If you checked the DB and especially the options table and haven't found their any mention of the old domain, then you should also  search for it in the source files. It is probably best to simply download the wp-content folder to your PC and use a search tool to search for it in the files.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was the JetPack overlay comments. The link was tied to wordpress.com. I simply unlinked the account, reinstalled jetpack and relinked using the new domain name.